# How to access email body in inbox list using InboxSDK?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, inboxsdk

I am trying to make a chrome extension for gmail and am currently tinkering around with InboxSDK but I am unable to figure out how do I access email body from the inbox list itself(without opening the email) to add labels depending on the content.

I get the threadRowView object but I am unsure what to do after that to get more details of the mail.
I think getElement() might be able to help somehow but I am unable to make sure how do I extract the mail from raw gmail DOM.
https://inboxsdk.github.io/inboxsdk-docs/lists/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am yet to find a way to do this directly only by using InboxSDK but there is a workaround which can help you get shorter descriptive text from the email which is seen on the inbox list.

```js
InboxSDK.load('1.0', 'YOUR_APP_ID').then(function(sdk) {
  sdk.Lists.registerThreadRowViewHandler(function(threadRowView) {
    var threadElement = threadRowView.getElement();
    var descriptiveText = threadElement.textContent;
    // do something based on the text
  });
});
```

[Documentation](https://inboxsdk.github.io/inboxsdk-docs/lists/#getelement)

I will update the answer if I am able to a better solution but I think one way to this properly should be using Official Gmail API and get the message using messageID.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

To access the email body from the inbox list using InboxSDK, you can use the `ThreadView.getThreadData()` method to get the thread data, which includes the message data for each message in the thread. From there, you can access the message body using the `getBodyText()` method.

Here's some sample code to get you started:

```js
InboxSDK.load('1.0', 'YOUR_APP_ID').then(function(sdk) {
  sdk.Lists.registerThreadRowViewHandler(function(threadRowView) {
    var threadView = threadRowView.getThreadView();
    threadView.getThreadData().then(function(threadData) {
      var messages = threadData.getMessages();
      for (var i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
        var message = messages[i];
        var body = message.getBodyText();
        // Do something with the body, like add labels based on content
      }
    });
  });
});
```

[official documentation](https://inboxsdk.github.io/inboxsdk-docs/lists/)

Comment: getThreadView() is not a function for threadRowView. :/